# How to skip a search if City name is not found in a csv file using Geopandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, geospatial, geopandas

All,

I am working on a project where I need to read a column from a csv file say "**City Name**", I have used **Geopandas** and iterating through the "**City**" column to fetch the **Latitude** and **Longitude** of the cities. However, the code gets stuck if it is not able to find the city details. I want to write a Try and Exception block using **Python** or if there is any other way to **skip the search if not found and move to the next row**.

I am attaching my code snippet below for reference:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import time
from pprint import pprint

app = Nominatim(user_agent='myapplication')
time.sleep(1)

def get_location_by_address(address):
    """This function returns a location as raw from an address
    will repeat until success"""
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        return app.geocode(address).raw
    except:
        return get_location_by_address(address)

data= pd.read_csv("City Details.csv")

for i in range(len(data['City Name'])):
    #print(data['City Name'][i])
    location = get_location_by_address(data['City Name'][i])
    #pprint(location)
    latitude = location["lat"]
    longitude = location["lon"]
    pprint(f" {data['City Name'][i]}, {latitude}, {longitude}")


**Output Sample:**

THIRUVANANTHAPURAM, 8.4882267, 76.947551'
' Chennai, 13.0836939, 80.270186'
' Gudur, 18.1600793, 79.5413501'
' Paradeep, 20.2685001, 86.65105802462674'
```

However, the next city name is "**Sangareddi**" and my code keeps on running but doesn't move to the next row. I have manually delete that particular row and restart the Kernel to proceed.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should check the exception and do something for a specific exception that would allow you to continue… your function in the case of not finding something or a real exception will never end. I imagine some exceptions it might be fine to rerun the same address, but for most of them you should probably move on…

Comment: Hi Jarvis, I understand the Exception block I need to raise but I need to know one thing, is there any option of timeout. Say it it is not able to search for the place in 5 secs it skips to the next row? I need to know that.

Comment: I would put a `try` block around the `location = get_loca…` code to catch your timeout or whatever exception you decide to `throw` or allow to bubble up.